# Express handlebar error : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

Tags: express, handlebars.js, sendgrid, nodemailer, express-handlebars

I am trying to send styled email with sendgrid, nodemailer@6.7.7, nodemailer-handlebars1 and expess-handlerbar@6

the folder structure involving sendemail

[image]

The send email function

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const logger = require("./logger");
const handlebars = require("nodemailer-handlebars");
const path = require("path");

const viewpath = path.join(__dirname, "../views");

const sendEmail = (options) => {

// the transporter that will send the mail
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service : process.env.EMAIL_SERVICE,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
    }
})

// for using express handlebars
transporter.use("compile", handlebars({
    viewEngine: "express-handlebars",
    viewPath: `${viewpath}`
}))

console.log(viewpath)

// mail options
const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    to: options.to,
    subject: options.subject,
    // html: options.html,
    text: options.text,
    template: "index"
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if(error){
        logger.error(`Send Mail Error : ${error}`)
    } else {
        logger.info(`Email sent successfully`)
    }
})
}

module.exports = sendEmail
```

When email is sent i get this error

[image]

When i change the view path variable to

```
const viewpath = path.join(__dirname, "../views/index.handlebars");
```

i get

[image]

If i uncomment the html inside the mailoptions and comment text and readjust the arguement{html} everywhere sendEmail() is invoked email is sent successfully. What could be the problem? And also what is the best practise?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for the `viewEngine` setting you should pass through options that will go to the rendering engine, not just the name of it. Currently, the rendering engine is looking for a layout for your email, but it doesn't look like you are using a layout, so try:

```js
const viewpath = path.join(__dirname, "../views");

  transporter.use(
    "compile",
    handlebars({
      viewEngine: {
        defaultLayout: false,
      },
      viewPath: viewpath,
    })
  );
```